# In which language is each Mono component developed?

Tags: .net, programming-languages, mono

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)#Mono_components), Mono has three main components:

- Core components
- Mono/Linux/GNOME development stack
- Microsoft compatibility stack

I want to know what the language or technology each one of those components is developed in.

**EDIT:**
I know that the some portions of the project is developed in C#, especially the old ones, but I want to know if the WHOLE project is developed in C#, or not.

Comment: As far as I understand it, Mono is implemented entirely in C#, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [runtime](http://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mono/) itself is written in C. The different [class libraries](http://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/) and [tools](http://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/), as well as the [C# compiler](http://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/mcs/) are entirely written in C#.

The only exception is the [VB compiler](http://github.com/mono/mono-basic/tree/master/vbnc/) and [VB libraries](http://github.com/mono/mono-basic/tree/master/vbruntime) that are written, well, in VB.

Answer (score 3):

You can see a breakdown of lines of code in individual languages [here](http://www.ohloh.net/p/mono/analyses/latest).

The core itself which has to communicate with lower-level operating system functions is mostly written in C, while the class library is mostly written in C#.

Comment: The only issue with the ohloh is that it takes into account a lot of things that are in SVN, such as moonlight for instance, but that are not directly part of Mono.

Comment: Johannes, they both share /trunk/moon which is where the Moonlight code lives in. I kind of have a clue you know :)

Comment: Argh, sorry. Overlooked that one. Too many that looked like `trunk/mono` and `trunk/moon` looking very similar ... bleh, I need coffee ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to the Mono [Subversion repository](http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/). From [The Compiling Mono From SVN](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_SVN):

> This assumes that you have a working mono installation, and that there's a C# compiler named 'mcs', and a corresponding IL runtime called 'mono'.

So I guess it is implemented in C#

Comment: Thanks for the link and the citation. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a educated guess, but the vm, jit and all the runtime stuff is probbly written in c or c++. The development stack like the interfaces to gnome api's, language libaries etc are probbly written in c sharp.

Microsoft compatibility stack is probbly written in c sharp implemented with the c sharp interfaces to native linux libaries.

It is a guess though. You can check yourself.

Answer (score -2):

mono is open source - why don't you just look at the source? see here http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/

Edit: To be less rude

One of the first things mono did was to build a self compiling C# compiler. I would assume that they still write most of the stuff in that or a direct descendant.

Comment: that could be the answer to almost any open-source question, and is not particularly helpful

Comment: If you're going to take the time to answer, you could at least post a link to the SCM to help the OP out

Answer (score -2):

The Mono compiler (mcs/gmcs) is written in C++.

The class libraries (System, System.Web, etc.) are written in C#.

Some of the low-level functionality that can't be done in C# (for example: P/Invoke, native windowing) is also written in C++.

Comment: Nope, the runtime is in C, the C# compiler is written in C#.